# Asmx dynamic compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-3.5, asmx

If I want to compile the source (cs) file of the web page, i simply use `Src` attribute instead of `CodeBehind` attribute in the Page directive, e.g.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Src="XXX.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Path.To.XXX" %>
```

which works perfectly with a source file that has the BuildAction set to Content. Is it possible to do the similar thing for an asmx web service ? The WebService directive doesn't support the `Src` attribute and when I use CodeBehind it simply can't find the class..

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I, personally, like to be certain of what code I have deployed, and deploying source code just doesn't do that for me.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but this is a specific situation at our company where we have a kind of "plugin" where we deploy source code. Strange as it may seem, there's very little I can change about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out it's enough to simply leave out the `CodeBehind` attribute and put the source directly in the asmx file - it is then compiled dynamically.